# Button with IBAction causes "Could not connect action, target class NSNibExternalObjectPlaceholder does not respond to -action" error

Tags: cocoa, nstableview, xcode-storyboard

I have a Storyboard scene which contains an NSTableView with an NSTableViewRow subclass. In this table view row, I have a button which I have wired up to an action in the view controller on the scene.

When the table loads, I am seeing this cryptic error from Xcode and the action never fires when I click the button:

```
Could not connect action, target class NSNibExternalObjectPlaceholder does not respond to -playVideo:
```

It looks like the file's owner never gets wired up.

Since these NSTableRowViews get instantiated programmatically, I checked to see if the owner is getting set, and indeed it is:

```
- (NSView *) tableView:(NSTableView *)tableView viewForTableColumn:(NSTableColumn *)tableColumn row:(NSInteger)row {
...
CombinedHistoryEntryTableCellView *cellView = [tableView makeViewWithIdentifier:@"deviceEvent" owner:self];
...
return cellView;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe I am experiencing a bug (and I will file a radar later) but I was able to work around the issue by wiring the button up to an action on the `CombinedHistoryEntryTableCellView` class in IB. Since the code needed to run the action was in the view controller I gave the cell view object a reference to the controller so that it could call it.

Still don't know why that was an issue, though, but if someone else experiences this that is a suitable workaround.